# How to store socket object of socket io in slice of redux toolkit?

Tags: react-redux, socket.io, redux-toolkit

How to store socket object of `socket.io` in slice of `redux toolkit`?

I would like to do something like:

```
const initialState = {
  socket: null
}

const socketSlice = createSlice({
  name: socket,
  initialState,
  reducers:{
    createSocket(state, action){
      state.socket = io("localhost:5000")
    },
    removeSocket(state, action){
      state.socket = null
    }
    // ...
  }
})
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:222 A non-serializable value was detected in the state
```

Help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and solved it using the following steps:

- Create a socket client in which I have a single instance of socket which I use to perform all socket related functions:

```py
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

class SocketClient {
  socket;

  connect() {
    this.socket = io.connect(process.env.SOCKET_HOST, { transports: ['websocket'] });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.socket.on('connect', () => resolve());
      this.socket.on('connect_error', (error) => reject(error));
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.socket.disconnect(() => {
        this.socket = null;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  emit(event, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.socket) return reject('No socket connection.');

      return this.socket.emit(event, data, (response) => {
        // Response is the optional callback that you can use with socket.io in every request. See 1 above.
        if (response.error) {
          console.error(response.error);
          return reject(response.error);
        }

        return resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  on(event, fun) {
    // No promise is needed here, but we're expecting one in the middleware.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.socket) return reject('No socket connection.');

      this.socket.on(event, fun);
      resolve();
    });
  }
}

export default SocketClient;
```

- Import it into my ***index.jsx*** file and initialize it:

```py
import SocketClient from './js/services/SocketClient';

export const socketClient = new SocketClient();
```

- Here's the whole code of my ***index.jsx*** file:

```py
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
//import meta image
import '@/public/assets/images/metaImage.jpg';
//styles
import '@/scss/global.scss';
//store
import store from '@/js/store/store';
//app
import App from './App';
//socket client
import SocketClient from './js/services/SocketClient';

export const socketClient = new SocketClient();

const container = document.getElementById('root'),
  root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

- I used **createAsyncThunk** function from **@reduxjs/toolkit**, because it automatically generates types like `pending`, `fulfilled` and `rejected`.
- Here's how I structure my reducer slice to connect and disconnect from web socket in redux:

```py
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { socketClient } from '../../../../index';

const initialState = {
  connectionStatus: '',
};

export const connectToSocket = createAsyncThunk('connectToSocket', async function () {
  return await socketClient.connect();
});

export const disconnectFromSocket = createAsyncThunk('disconnectFromSocket', async function () {
  return await socketClient.disconnect();
});

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(connectToSocket.pending, (state) => {
      state.connectionStatus = 'connecting';
    });
    builder.addCase(connectToSocket.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.connectionStatus = 'connected';
    });
    builder.addCase(connectToSocket.rejected, (state) => {
      state.connectionStatus = 'connection failed';
    });
    builder.addCase(disconnectFromSocket.pending, (state) => {
      state.connectionStatus = 'disconnecting';
    });
    builder.addCase(disconnectFromSocket.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.connectionStatus = 'disconnected';
    });
    builder.addCase(disconnectFromSocket.rejected, (state) => {
      state.connectionStatus = 'disconnection failed';
    });
  },
});
export default appSlice.reducer;
```

- Here how I connect and disconnect in ***App.jsx*** file:

```py
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(connectToSocket());

    return () => {
      if (connectionStatus === 'connected') {
        dispatch(disconnectFromSocket());
      }
    };
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [dispatch]);
```

- You can do the following if you want to **emit** to web socket:

```py
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { socketClient } from '../../../../index';

const initialState = {
  messageStatus: '', //ideally it should come from the BE
  messages: [],
  typingUsername: '',
};

export const sendMessage = createAsyncThunk('sendMessage', async function ({ message, username }) {
  return await socketClient.emit('chat', { message, handle: username });
});

const chatSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'chat',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(sendMessage.pending, (state) => {
      state.messageStatus = 'Sending';
    });
    builder.addCase(sendMessage.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.messageStatus = 'Sent successfully';
    });
    builder.addCase(sendMessage.rejected, (state) => {
      state.messageStatus = 'Send failed';
    });
  },
});
export default chatSlice.reducer;
```

- You can do the following if you want to listen to an event from web socket:

```py
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { socketClient } from '../../../../index';

const initialState = {
  messageStatus: '', //ideally it should come from the BE
  messages: [],
  typingUsername: '',
};

export const fetchMessages = createAsyncThunk(
  'fetchMessages',
  async function (_, { getState, dispatch }) {
    console.log('state ', getState());
    return await socketClient.on('chat', (receivedMessages) =>
      dispatch({ type: 'chat/saveReceivedMessages', payload: { messages: receivedMessages } })
    );
  }
);

const chatSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'chat',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    saveReceivedMessages: (state, action) => {
      state.messages.push(action.payload.messages);
      state.typingUsername = '';
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchMessages.pending, () => {
      // add a state if you would like to
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchMessages.fulfilled, () => {
      // add a state if you would like to
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchMessages.rejected, () => {
      // add a state if you would like to
    });
  },
});
export default chatSlice.reducer;
```